# Unexpected Error C2632: 'char' followed by 'char' is illegal

Tags: visual-c++, compiler-errors

I am having a piece of code as

```
    typedef unsigned char   _uint8;
    typedef unsigned short  _uint16;
    typedef unsigned int    _uint32;
    typedef float           _float32;

    typedef char            _int8;
    typedef short           _int16;
    typedef int             _int32;
```

I'm getting error at the lines that are in the last three lines

The error message is

error C2632: 'char' followed by 'char' is illegal
error C2632: 'short' followed by 'short' is illegal

error C2632: 'int' followed by 'int' is illegal

Comment: Is this protected by an include guard symbol or a #pragma once?

Comment: Does this code compile by itself? What comes before it?

Comment: You have a `#define _int8 char` somewhere

Answer (score 2):

Those types have already been created via `typedef` (maybe) or `#define` (more likely) before your code tries to do it; taking a look at the preprocessor output (if that's possible with Visual-C++) may help you track down why that is.

Answer (score 2):

In C and C++, it is illegal (invokes undefined behavior) to define your own identifiers which start with an underscore.  Only the compiler and standard library are allowed to use names that begin with an underscore.  It appears that these particular names (`_int8`, etc) have already been defined as macros or intrinsic types.

You must choose different names.

### Citation

From n1570 §7.1.3,

> All identifiers that begin with an underscore are always reserved for use as identifiers with file scope in both the ordinary and tag name spaces.
>
> ...
>
> If the program declares or defines an identifier in a context in which it is reserved (other than as allowed by 7.1.4), or defines a reserved identifier as a macro name, the behavior is undefined.

Therefore, by attempting to define the type `_int8`, your program invokes undefined behavior.  "Undefined behavior" is a technical term, and it means that the compiler makes **no guarantees:** maybe you will get an error message, maybe it will work as you expect, or maybe something else will happen entirely.  Maybe there will be no error message, but your program won't work correctly.

### Example

Try compiling the following code in Visual Studio...

```
int main()
{
    _int8 x = 1;
    return 0;
}
```

It compiles... which means that `_int8` is already in use by the compiler to define a type.  It appears to be an **undocumented** type, since an MSDN search turns up nothing.  But you're not allowed to define your own `_int8` anyway.

Comment: But in the same set of code, how is that for the first four lines, it does not throw any error, even though they start with underscore...

Comment: @Matt: "Undefined behavior" does not guarantee an error message, just that it is not guaranteed to work.  Maybe it will work, maybe it will be an error, and maybe it will do something completely unexpected.

Comment: In general, identifiers that start with an underscore are simply reserved, they are not necessarily illegal: [C-Faq regarding namespaces](http://c-faq.com/decl/namespace.html). The fact that `_int8` would compile on it's own suggests that Visual Studio has broken the ANSI standard.

Comment: @DrRobotNinja: Wrong, read that section again.  From n1570 §7.1.3: "No other identifiers are reserved. If the program declares or defines an identifier in a context in which it is reserved (other than as allowed by 7.1.4), or defines a reserved identifier as a macro name, **the behavior is undefined.**" (emphasis added)

Comment: @DietrichEpp: Ah, okay. I misread what was meant by "file scope." in n1570 7.1.3.1.2